# Add a relation between table in PHPMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want create a relation between different tables in phymyadmin with mysql.
I want to add cascade option but I don't always see the cascade option every time I add relation.

[image: No Cascade Option]
[image: Cascade option available]

For example in first image when I relate usergroupid id in usergroup and users table there is not cascade option available. But as in second image when i relate invoice id in invoicedetails and tripmaster table I gets the cascade options availabale.

So I'm no able to understand why cascade option is not available every time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several conditions that your tables and columns need to meet in order to create foreign key constraints.

One that you are missing in your example and that is visible from the screenshot, is the length of the integer value. They both need to have the same length (and sign...) so `int(5)` and `int(11)` are not compatible.

You also need indices on the columns, etc. see the [manual on foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for all requirements.

Answer (score 0):

When you build relationships like this, the key and its matching foreign key must have exactly the same datatype.

So in your first example, the integers are of different sizes (int(5) and int(11) thus MySql cannot create the required constraints and you cannot enable cascade deletes or updates.

In your second example, its not clear from the screenshot but I assume that the datatypes match.

Also ensure that integer datatypes are both signed or unsigned. If one is signed and the other unsigned, you'll run into the same problem.

Comment: In the first screen shot, I'm adding foreign key usergroup id in usergroup and users table in which usergroupis int(2) in both the tables but even if I'm not getting cascade option. and in second screenshot even if size are different for invoiceid (int(5) and int(11)) cascade option is available.

Comment: Best if you can put some table defintions and sample data into sqlfiddle.com then we can take a more detailed look.